# how to call startActivity(intent) from the phoneStateListener class?

Tags: android

i am creating an application to send mail. I am using the class which extends the phoneStateListener class. this gives the problem at the time of startActivity function which says that  "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type PhoneCallListener" where PhoneCallListener is a class extended by phonestatelistener and following code is written into it.

```
          String to = "a.crack@gmail.com";
          String subject = "testing";
          String message = "this is it";
         Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});

          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

please help me with how to start the activity so as to send my mail.

Comment: you kinda need a context to start an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Intent in;
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                in = new Intent(context, Second.class);
                    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(in);

                }
            }
    }
```

Make sure that you add receiver in menifest file.

Comment: is it require to explicitly call the onReceive() or it is implicitly done when situation is alike?
if so plz tell in which condition is it called and a bit of its functionality.

Comment: is it not so that the onReceive method is called when the application receives the mail???

Comment: It's better to call it explicitly in menifest file. <receiver android:name=".package.MyPhoneReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Also add the permission in menifest.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />,     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />